# Oracle delete procedure is not working correctly

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sql-delete

This is my oracle stored procedure. I want to delete certain id when I pass data to procedure, but when I perform this proc. I get deleted everything that my trable has.

Can someone please check this out

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Delete(
    id IN number)

AS
BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Users WHERE Users.id_user= id;
END;
/
```

I have tried to put :

```
DELETE FROM Users WHERE Users.id_user == id;
```

Then I get compilation error.

Comment: To be extra safe I'd use: `delete from users where users.id_user = Delete.id;` but because your procedure is called "Delete" you'd get a compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `DELETE FROM Users WHERE id_user = id;` ?

Using `==` is not valid SQL for an equality check.

I still don't see why are you getting all rows deleted. `DELETE FROM Users WHERE Users.id_user = id` should be working properly.

More information on the [DELETE STATEMENT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems014.htm) syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. When I pass an Id that doesn't exist in the table, everything gets deleted.

If the id exists in the table, then the procedure runs as I want it to run.

```
PROCEDURE tests
( jobnr IN varchar2,
 x IN number,
 menu in varchar2 default '1')
IS
counter number := 0;

BEGIN
delete from table_test where jobnr = jobnr;

if sql%notfound or sql%rowcount=0 then
        rollback;
end if;

WHILE counter < x
LOOP
    insert into table_test ( cskey, telnr, seq, jobnr, menu ) values ('Test'||counter, counter, counter, jobnr, menu );
    counter := counter + 1;
END LOOP;
commit;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Store input into local variable and then use this variable in your query. This worked for me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Delete(
    id IN number)

AS
v_id Number;
BEGIN
        v_id := id;
        DELETE FROM Users WHERE Users.id_user= v_id;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(ID NUMBER);

TABLE CREATED.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DeleteIDS(
    id IN number)

AS
BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Users WHERE id= id;
END;
/

PROCEDURE CREATED.
```

Here, in the table users id is there and also if you specify id in the declaration of procedure then that procedure deletes all the data. 
so,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DeleteIDS(
    idS IN number)

AS
BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Users WHERE id= idS;
END;
/
PROCEDURE CREATED.
```

Now,

```
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(10);

1 ROW INSERTED.

INSERT INTO USER VALUES(20);

1 ROW INSERTED.

COMMIT;
```

Now, execute the procedure

```
SQL>EXEC DELETEIDS(10);

PL/SQL PROGRAM SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED.

SELECT * FROM USERS;

ID
---
2
```